# Do Tallbird nests reappear after being burned?

Tags: dont-starve

I noticed that an empty Tallbird nest will be reinhabited with a new Tallbird after a few days, which will eventually spawn an egg. But do the nests also appear? I haven't had enough luck to figure it out. The game wiki lists Tallbirds as renewable, but I'm not sure if it means just hatching the eggs and waiting for a nest to be reinhabited.

In case a nest *accidentally* burns to ashes, will it reappear after some time along with a new Tallbird?

Comment: Tallbirds will not re-create destroyed nests. I'm not sure however if a nest can just re-spawn.

Comment: Not an answer, but I've never seen one reappear. Doesn't prove it can't, but I deem it very likely that it won't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not explicitly stated, but the Don't Starve Wiki has tallbird nests listed as non-renewable resources.  I take this to mean that they do not spontaneously re-spawn if burned.

[The List of Non-Renewable Resources](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Non-Renewable)

That said, if you wish to *cause* one to spawn you can have the game spawn one for you.

In-game hit <kbd>`</kbd> and type:

> **DebugSpawn("tallbirdnest")**

A tallbird nest with an egg will instantly appear in front of you.  It will hatch immediately into a tallbird who will start to attack you for being so close to its nest!

To make the console disappear hit <kbd>Control-L</kbd>.

Comment: That's basically cheating. I was wondering if nests reappeared on their own at their previous locations. I wish there was a way to craft a nest from beefalo wool.

Comment: I never claimed it wasn't cheating.